# django template blocks within blocks

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a main page **base.html**. Inside of it, there is a **{% block main_content %}**:

```
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid p-3">

        {% block main_content %}
        {% endblock %}

    </div>
</main>
```

I slot my pages into that main content block.

I now have to create a lot of pages for some internal documentation, that would probably end up being small enough.

I then created a **documentation.html** page with another **{% block documentation %}** inside of the **{% block main_content %}**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}

{% block title %}Documentation{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
<!-- CSS specific to documentation goes here -->
{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}

    {% block documentation %}

    {% endblock documentation %}

{% endblock main_content %}

{% block end_scripts %}
<!-- Scripts specific to documentation go here -->
{% endblock end_scripts %}
```

I do it this way because there will be some scripts and css specific changes to this documentation section of my page that will be shared among a whole buch of sub-pages. I would then include them **once** in this **documentation.html** page, and just change the content inside the **{% block documentation %}** tags. Then I created a test **test_page.html** like this:

```
{% extends 'documentation.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}

{% block title %}Main Page{% endblock %}

{% block documentation %}

<p>Hello world!</p>

{% endblock documentation %}
```

So **test_page.html** would "slot" into **documentation.html** that then "slots" into **base.html**.

The reason I do this is, each small documentation block that would "slot" into **documentation.html** would share CSS and scripts, but the actual readable content would change.

For some reason this is not working. **documentation.html** is indeed "slotting" into and extending **base.html**, but **test_page.html** is **NOT** extending into **documentation.html**.

This is my **TEMPLATES** section on **settings.py**:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I don't really understand why "Hello world!" in **test_page.html** is not showing up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In summary, this is what I thought would happen with the tags and content:

```
######## This is base.html ########
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid p-3">

        {% block main_content %}

            ######## This is documentation.html ########

            {% block documentation %}

                ######## This is test.html ########

                <p>Hello world!</p>

            {% endblock documentation %}

        {% endblock main_content %}

    </div>
</main>
```

So **"Hello world!"** inside **test.html** goes into **documentation.html** which goes into **base.html**. This is not the case and I don't understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:** *It's not possible.*

To get blocks within blocks you can use `{{ block.super }}`

base.html ->

```
<div id='contnet'>{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>
```

page1.html ->

```
{% extends base %} 
{% block content %}This Content Will Always Be Here {% endblock %}
```

page2.html ->

```
{% extends page1 %}
{% block content %}  New Content, Old Content: {{ block.super }} {% endblock %}
```

page2 will result like this

```
<div id='content'>New Content, Old Content: This Content Will Always Be Here</div>
```

However what you can't do, (if i'm not mistaking) is in page1, in that content block YOU CANNOT add a new block there like you are trying to do in your documentation.html page.

One solution is to use django flatpages, or something similar (as opposed to template inheritance)

Answer (score -1):

This is a generic example but maybe it could help you.

When you are using heritage between files, you need to make something like this.

Base.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        {% load staticfiles %}
        {% load static %}


        <title> Your Title </title>

    </head>


    <body>

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}  

    </body>
</html>
```

Then, if you want to add content in your base file, you can create a new HTML file which looks like this :

```
{% extends 'Base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    Your content will display to Base file

{% endblock content %}
```

if you follow this process, it should work without issues.

### Edit :

According to your templates directory, if this template is located in your base directory, try to modify this :

```
str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
```

to this :

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Comment: I have that. My problem begins when I try to (in your example) add a new block inside the content block, AKA, a sub-block, IE: `{% block content %} {% block sub_block_content %} {% endblock sub_block_content %} {% endblock content %}`

By all guides and documentation I've read, this **should** work, but in my case it doesn't, and I don't understand why.

Comment: @Mormoran : did you get this to work? I have the same issue.